# getTableMappings method is not present in Hibernate 5

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I want to upgrade my hibernate version 4.x.x to 5.x.x. But after upgrading i can not find getTableMappings method in Configuration class of hibernate 5. I need this before building sessionfactory. Earlier it was available in hibernate. What can be the right solution for it ?

Comment: Could you please explain how do you use `getTableMappings`?

Comment: Before building sessionfactory i am injecting Hibernate Configuration object in a class where i have written a method that is getting all table mappings from this object

Comment: I need to get all mapped table before building the session factory

Comment: Do you use spring boot?

Comment: no, can you suggest any other way to achieve the same in hibernate 5

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can achieve what you want only by refusing usage [legacy bootstrapping](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#appendix-legacy-bootstrap):

> `Configuration` is semi-deprecated but still available for use, in a **limited form** that eliminates these drawbacks. "Under the covers", `Configuration` uses the new bootstrapping code, so the things available there are also available here in terms of auto-discovery.

As described [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-native), you can bootstrap a Hibernate `SessionFactory` in the following way:

```java
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass;

// ...

StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
     .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
     .build();
MetadataSources metadata = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry);
Metadata meta = metadata.buildMetadata();

// Retrieves the PersistentClass entity metadata representation for all known entities.
for (PersistentClass pClass : meta.getEntityBindings())
{
   // ...
}
      
sessionFactory = meta.buildSessionFactory();
```